# Creating components with listener during runtime in java

Tags: java, runtime, components

I am trying to make a programm which contains a button that first make's you choose an image using an already working JFileChooser, and then adds a new component to the window with the selected image displayed inside it, along with an mouse event listener .
My problem is: I want that you are able to import multiple objecs of the same class using this button, so that they are able to exist at the same time, and make them all have the mouse listener.

I am quite new to java so don't wonder if there is some totally obvious solution I missed out.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. Simply use 1 variable of the object type and then always declare a new object to it. The listeners are beeing created in the contructors of the object.